# Shutdown, hibernate and suspend not working

Tags: linux, shutdown, hibernate, asus-laptop, elementaryos

I just installed ElementaryOS on my laptop (ASUS ROG GL552VW-CN273T). I got everything working just fine except for when I want to suspend, hibernate, or shut down my laptop.

Shutdown:
If I shutdown, the following thing happens:

```
[  14.799618] r8159 0000:03:00.1 enp3s0f1: rtl_counters_cond == 1 (loop: 1000, delay: 10)
[  14.811149] r8159 0000:03:00.1 enp3s0f1: rtl_counters_cond == 1 (loop: 1000, delay: 10).
[  14.822476] r8159 0000:03:00.1 enp3s0f1: rtl_counters_cond == 1 (loop: 1000, delay: 10).
[  14.834316] r8159 0000:03:00.1 enp3s0f1: rtl_counters_cond == 1 (loop: 1000, delay: 10).
```

The only way to shut my laptop down is by holding the power button till it shuts down.

If I close my laptop lid (it's set to suspend) or click suspend on the power menu options, the screen stays on but goes black, the keyboard backlight stays on and the fan keeps spinning. Hibernate does the same thing. The only way to fix this is to hold the power button till it shuts down.

This is quite annoying because I always have to shut down the laptop manually, and since I use it for school it does take quite some time.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Xavierjazz well, i thought it was quite clear what my question was but I added it.